# How to make the DropDownListFor Don't repeat the Database data with the static list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a DropDownListFor a static list of numbers of months if i select the first month 1 and make edit will find the DropDownListFor repeat the first month like this
[image]

DropDownListFor Code :

```
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FinancialMonths, (Model.FinancialInfo == null || Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate == null) ? String.Empty : Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate.Value.Month.ToString(), new { @class = "description-text" })
```

Note : the FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth is a Metadata element to make it as a View model.

Code of the ViewBag.FinancialMonths:

```
        ViewBag.FinancialMonths = ListOfNumbers(1, 12).Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.ToString(), Value = m.ToString() });`
```

Code of the ListOfNumbers:

```
    public List<int> ListOfNumbers(int startNum, int endNum)
    {
        List<int> listOfNumbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = startNum; i <= endNum; i++)
        {
            listOfNumbers.Add(i);
        }
        return listOfNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: `new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12))` is all you need.

Comment: i like to use this Enumerable.Range but i need the selected item from the database shown in the first element as selected from the list

Comment: Then you just set the value of property `FinancialExpiryMonth` to match the option you want selected in the GET method before you pass the model to the view - if its (say) `model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth = 3;` then the 3rd option will be selected - thats how model binding works - it binds to the value of your property!

Comment: Okey that's right , thanks so much , but i need to ask if can i add a text to the SelectList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "1" that you see is a placeholder and it is generated by

```
(Model.FinancialInfo == null || Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate == null) ? String.Empty : Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate.Value.Month.ToString()
```

Replace the dropdown definition with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FinancialMonths, "Please select...", new { @class = "description-text" })
```

And you will see 'Please select...' as a placeholder

In order so pre-select a month simply assign a value to `model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth`

Comment: but i need the selected item from the database if i make edit, your code means i make the user must reenter the date, in facts he already select it

Comment: In order so pre-select a month simply assign a value to  `model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth` when you create a model in controller action before passing it to view

Answer (score 0):

Just By use the Lambda expresion in the `Enumerable.Range` and choose the selected condition is true when the Model have a value

```
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = x.ToString(),
               Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x),
               Selected = (Model.FinancialInfo == null || Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate == null) ? false : true
           }), "Month", new { @class = "description-text" })
```