# How to add item to a DropDownlistFor which have a Enumerable.Range list items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `DropDownListFor` with a static selectList 
Code:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth,
  new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12)), 
                (Model.FinancialInfo == null 
                  || Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate == null) 
                  ? String.Empty 
                  : null, 
  new { @class = "description-text" })
```

i need the first item is word `Month` How can i do that with this static `DropDownListFor` ?

[image: This is example for what i need to do!]

Comment: Replace the 3rd parameter with `"Month"`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke it will be month but in the edit action need the selected item is a value not the `"Month"`

Comment: need to choose the SelectedItem

Comment: I explained that in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585332/how-to-make-the-dropdownlistfor-dont-repeat-the-database-data-with-the-static-l). You need to set the value of your property `FinancialExpiryMonth` in the GET method to match the value of one of the options (and pass the model to the view)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally Solved just to add the selected = true when the item equal the `Model Value`

```
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = x.ToString(),
               Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x),
           }), "Month", new { @class = "description-text" })
```

Comment: This is wrong. Its the value of the property your binding to that determines what is selected. If the value of property is `FinancialExpiryMonth` is `3`, then `"March"` will be selected. If the value of `FinancialExpiryMonth` is not between 1 and 12, the the first option will be selected. Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a property.

Comment: but he cannot add another value not in the selectlist

Comment: What does that have to do with my comment? Delete the `Selected = (Model.FinancialInfo.....` bit and you will see exactly the same result!

Comment: but must add this condition in the first page lines `@{...}` to make this validation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you checking in your `DropDownListFor` but i suggest you to do it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinancialInfo.FinancialExpiryMonth,
    //Genaration of month names
 Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x=> new SelectListItem
 {
    Value = x.ToString(),
    Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x)
 }), 
 "Month", //First Value if nothing selected
 new { @class = "description-text" })
```

Comment: the month here is a place holder

Comment: @AhmedHossamAlhansy can you elaborate more?

Comment: i need this list have a string called `"month"` and the selected item in the list is the value of `Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate.Value.Month.ToString()`

Comment: need choose the Selected item from list equal to `Model.FinancialInfo.ExpiryDate.Value.Month.toString()'`